# If-else condition in visual basic to delete a record from SQL Server if record exist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, if-statement

I have written code in VB to delete a table record from database using inputbox (through user choice), but I have one problem when user inserts wrong value it still shows the "Record Successfully Deleted" MessageBox!

How to set the "if condition" to display record does not exist instead of showing successful deletion message?

Sorry this is my 1st post here that's why it is long! :p

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btndelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
        Try
            Dim isbn As Long = InputBox("Enter Book ISBN", "Delete")
            'First will delete the dependant record from published_by, book_return, memberbook_issue because
            'it can not be deleted by applying on cascade delete or update cause it has composite primary key.

            cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from published_by where isbn =" & isbn, cn)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from book_return where isbn =" & isbn, cn)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from memberbook_issue where isbn =" & isbn, cn)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from book where isbn = " & isbn, cn)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select b.staff_id, b.pub_id, b.sub_code, b.isbn, b.book_name, b.author, b.price, b.rack_no, b.no_of_books, pby.vol_no, pby.pub_date  from book b join published_by pby on b.isbn = pby.isbn", cn)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgvbook.DataSource = dt
            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Deleted from current table & dependant table(s)", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Not Completed Because OF The Following Error " & "%" & ex.Message & "%", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: `...that's why it is long` not quite long enough.  See [Ask]

Comment: If you post your code we would be able to help you

Comment: Can I post it in comment section?

Comment: post it in your question... click edit and add your code

Comment: please insert in your question sample data, the expected result and what you have tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the number of rows affected from SQL Server to VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821784/how-do-i-retrieve-the-number-of-rows-affected-from-sql-server-to-vb-net)

Comment: @Mych I just edited my post and added the code kindly check it now!

Comment: Study the link that @the_lotus provided...and use SQL parameters

Comment: You should really look into fixing your SQL Injection vulnerabilities...

Comment: @Plutonix I have read what "the_lotus" shared but couldn't get much from it can you please just show me where to add the if-else condition to give user prompt in-case the inserted value does not exist in database?

Comment: Seriously?  what part of `RowsEffected = Comand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is confusing?  study means study, not glance at.  If it returns 0 it means there was no row with that isbn

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix I will re-read it :p

Comment: And whatever you do you need to parameterize your queries immediately if not sooner. What you posted is a textbook example of the sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you I will try to optimize my code

Comment: SQL injection has nothing to do with optimized code. When you directly execute a string you are vulnerable. You should do some digging on sql injection and understand what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you really need to look into parameterizing your query. You should also look to encapsulate this into a stored procedure for easier reading and maintainablity.  Those things aside, you can accomplish all of this in one database call.

This snippet should produce the expected results.  Please double check the data type on the `SqlParameter` -- I guessed what it could be.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn = @isbn) " _
    & " BEGIN " _
    & " delete from published_by where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from book_return where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from memberbook_issue where isbn = @isbn; " _
    & " delete from book where isbn = @isbn;" _
    & " SELECT 1; " _
    & " END " _
    & " ELSE SELECT 0", cn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@isbn", SqlDBType.VarChar, 20) With {.Value = isbn})

cn.Open()
Dim returnValue as Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
If returnValue = 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Deleted from current table & dependant table(s)", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @InbetweenWeekends I understood every part of the code you shared with me and it is working. only one thing I have used "numeric(13,0)" in SQL and Integer in VB.NET for ISBN! now what datatype should I use instead of varchar in your code to match with the datatype I provided in my code?

Comment: @Hazmat If you haven't looked it up yet, then for the sake of people seeing this in the future, `New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@isbn", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal, .Precision = 13, .Scale = 0, .Value = isbn}`.

Comment: @Hazmat - your answer is found in Andrew's comment.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Morton and "InBetweenWeekends you guys were very helplful 